# Show minor tick labels in Matlab. Semilog plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Im triying to create a semilogy plot where I can see the labels of the minor ticks. The data I'm plotting spans from 292 to 1138. So by default the semilogy plot only shows the label in the 1000. I would need to show also the labels in the minor ticks (with a smaller font would be awesome) since only one number in the entire y axis is not very informative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See (possibly): [Why are there no minor ticks for my "semilog" plots in MATLAB 6.5 (R13)?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97982-why-are-there-no-minor-ticks-for-my-semilog-plots-in-matlab-6-5-r13)

Comment: Hi excaza, as I was comenting bellow, that's a bug in R13. However I'm using R14, and this question is not really about the ticks but about the ticks labels. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [there's a bug](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97982-why-are-there-no-minor-ticks-for-my-semilog-plots-in-matlab-6-5-r13) on Matlab, which makes it not possible to label minor ticks. (thanks @excasa)

[One thing you could do](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html) is setting the `gca`'s `YTick` property as a vector of increasing values. Then, there would be labels where you want (even though they would not be minor ticks anymore, but normal ticks).

Example:

```
ax = gca; %get current axis
ax.XTick = [-3*pi -2*pi -pi 0 pi 2*pi 3*pi];
ax.YTick = [-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1];

% For R2014a and earlier:
% ax = gca;
% set(ax,'XTick',[-3*pi -2*pi -pi 0 pi 2*pi 3*pi])
% set(ax,'YTick',[-1 -0.5 0 0.5 1])
```

You could, also, activate the grid for minor ticks `set(gca,'YminorGrid','on')`, so you have a better view of the values (even they not being labeled).

Comment: I'm looking for a way of doing it automatically. If you have several (hundreds) of plots that method is painful. Moreover, and of greater relevance, that example doesn't work if you use semilog instead of plot

Comment: Now i see where I misunderstood you, as you want to label the minor ticks, and my answer is only about the normal sized ticks... Well, you could replace the minor ticks for normal ticks (because, as 'excasa' commented, it really seems like a bug), or you could enable the minor grid (`set(gca,'YminorGrid','on')`) to have a better idea of the value and position of minor tick's reference. I'm editing the answer right away.

Comment: That bug you mention was for the r13. They corrected it in the r14. However, The bug is about the minorTicks marks, but those are the little lines perpendicular to the axis. My question is about the minorTicks Labels, that is the number next to the tick mark and outside the bounding box ;-)    The YminorGrid is useful, although I aready knew how to do that, is a nice visual aid. Not enough for my reviewers though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to be possible... I checked the [axes properties](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html), it seems the only thing one could do is setting minor ticks "on" or "off", besides of labeling normal ticks. That's as far as I got...